# job aborted while writing parquet to s3 via glue jobs

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, pyspark, aws-glue, aws-glue-spark

My code looks like below which consists of transformations:

```
dictionaryDf = spark.read.option("header", "true").csv(
            "s3://...../.csv")

        web_notif_data = fullLoad.cache()
        web_notif_data.persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK)
        print("::::::data has been loaded::::::::::::")
        distinct_campaign_name = web_notif_data.select(
            trim(web_notif_data.campaign_name).alias("campaign_name")).distinct()
        web_notif_data.createOrReplaceTempView("temp")
        variablesList = Config.get('web', 'variablesListWeb')
        web_notif_data = spark.sql(variablesList)
        web_notif_data.persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK)
        web_notif_data = web_notif_data.withColumn("camp", regexp_replace("campaign_name", "_", ""))
        web_notif_data = web_notif_data.drop("campaign_name")
        web_notif_data = web_notif_data.withColumnRenamed("camp", "campaign_name")
        web_notif_data = web_notif_data.withColumn("channel", lit("web_notification"))
        web_notif_data.createOrReplaceTempView("data")
        campaignTeamWeb = Config.get('web', 'campaignTeamWeb')
        web_notif_data = spark.sql(campaignTeamWeb)
        web_notif_data.persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK)

        distinct_campaign_name = distinct_campaign_name.withColumn("camp", F.regexp_replace(
            F.lower(F.trim(col("campaign_name"))),
            "[^a-zA-Z0-9]", ""))
        output_df3 = (
            distinct_campaign_name.withColumn("cname_split",
                                              F.explode(F.split(F.lower(F.trim(col("campaign_name"))), "_")))
                .join(
                dictionaryDf,
                (
                        (
                                (F.col("function") == "contains") &
                                F.col("camp").contains(F.col("terms"))
                        ) |
                        (
                                (F.col("function") == "match") &
                                F.col("campaign_name").contains("_") &
                                (F.col("cname_split") == F.col("terms"))
                        )
                ),
                "left"
            )
                .withColumn(
                "empty_is_other",
                F.when(
                    (
                            F.col("product").isNull() &
                            F.col("product_category").isNull()
                    ),
                    "other"
                )
            )
                .withColumn(
                "rn",
                F.row_number().over(
                    Window.partitionBy("campaign_name")
                        .orderBy(
                        F.when(
                            F.col("function").isNull(), 3
                        ).when(
                            F.col("function") == "match", 2
                        ).otherwise(1),
                        F.length(F.col("terms")).desc(),
                        F.col("product").isNull()
                    )
                )
            )
                .filter("rn=1")
                .select(
                "campaign_name",
                F.coalesce("product", "empty_is_other").alias("prod"),
                F.coalesce("product_category", "empty_is_other").alias("prod_cat"),
            )
                .na.fill("")
        )
        print(":::::::::::transformations have been done finally::::::::::::")
        web_notif_data1 = web_notif_data  # Just taking the backup of DF in case something goes wrong
        web_notif_data = web_notif_data.drop("campaign_name")
        web_notif_data = web_notif_data.withColumnRenamed("temp_campaign_name", "campaign_name")
        veryFinalDF = web_notif_data.join(output_df3, "campaign_name", "left_outer")
        # veryFinalDF.show(truncate=False)
        veryFinalDF.write.mode("overwrite").parquet(aggregatedPath)
        print("::::final data have been written successfully::::::")
```

where `fullLoad` is the data frame that reads from the Redshift table.This code works fine on `0.2 Million` records. However, in production for 15 days, data could be around a `minimum` of `25 Million` records. I don't know the size since the data is stored in the redshift table and we are reading from it and then processing the data. I am running this code via `Glue` jobs and it gets stuck on the last line i.e while writing the data as parquet. It gives me the below error:

[image]

I tried running it with `30` executors. It takes around `20 mins` to load the data from `Redshift` into the `fullLoad` dataframe. What else can be done to avoid this error? I am new to AWS and Glue jobs.

Comment: Any suggestions ?

Comment: Can you share the number of Partitions in veryFinalDF ? Likely you need to repartition that dataframe before writing to S3? yes  veryFinalDF.num_partitions() should be fine.

Comment: It is not able to reach the last line of the code. It is not able to display count() on the initial dataset itself. While displaying the count() it gives the heartbeat error